# Response mapping in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there any way which can map my response of API into the required format in azure APIM

e.g. if my API gave a response like

```
customer:  {
"id" : 123
}
```

the output I will be needing is

```
customer: {
"customerID": 123
}
```

Is there any way without using a set-body policy?
or is there any way where I can define logic which can map `Id` value to `customerID`

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

**Simple JSON**

If you have simple JSON as you have shown in the question, then [Find and Replace transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#Findandreplacestringinbody) policy can be helpful.
Please note that this policy would just perform string replace.  It does not know anything about JSON format.  So you have to be extra careful while replacing anything.

But I assume the JSON might not be that simple in real world scenarios.

**Complex JSON**

You can implement your custom logic by using [Set Body Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody) Policy.

Code would be something like below.  You can get the JObject and then [query and update](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) it.

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200"> 
    <set-body> 
    @{ 
        JObject inBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>();

        // Razor view syntax so you can write code as per your need
        JObject customer= (JObject)inBody["customer"];
        var customerIdValue = ((string)customer["id"]);
        customer["CustomerId"] = customerId;

        customer.Property("id").Remove();

        // assuming customer has a description property
        customer.Property("description").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("customerId", customerIdValue));
        return inBody.ToString(); 
    } 
    </set-body>
  </when>
</choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also use set-body with liquid template in outbound of your operation:

```
<set-body template="liquid">{
    "customer": {
        "customerID": {{body.customer.id}}
    }
}</set-body>
```

Comment: i know this way but what if there is complex object where i need to map more property values

Comment: cant we have schema defined and just do the mapping of response to it

Comment: Liquid templates allow for that. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Find and Replace String in Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#Findandreplacestringinbody) policy for a simple solution.